# Place the pandastable in a given place tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm unable to find a way to place the a table in Ktinker. I'm using pandastable to display the table.

```
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
from tkintertable import TableCanvas

def display_csv_file(self,parent):
    try:
        
        self.file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = '/Desktop',
                                                    title = 'Select csv file',
                                                    filetypes = (('csv file','*.csv'),
                                                                 ('csv file','*.csv')))
        df = pd.read_csv(self.file_name)
          
        if (len(df)== 0):
            msg.showinfo('No records', 'No records')
            
        # Now display the DF in 'Table' object
        # under'pandastable' module
        
        
        self.f2 = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.table = Table(self.f2, dataframe=df,read_only=True, height=300, width=600)
        self.f2.pack(padx=4, pady = 100)
        self.table.show()
      
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
        msg.showerror('Error in opening file',e)
```

I'm getting it displayed like below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to move this table along the y axis

Comment: `display_csv_file()` looks like inside a class (based on the `self` argument), but it is not.  Also there is no code on how the function is executed.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

As you told in the comment, It seems that display_csv_file is a class method, so I wrap that function with a simple class, and it works fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import filedialog
from pandastable import Table


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = None
        self.f2 = None
        self.table = None

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.display_csv_file(self.root)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def display_csv_file(self, parent):
        try:

            self.file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop',
                                                        title='Select csv file',
                                                        filetypes=(('csv file', '*.csv'),
                                                                   ('csv file', '*.csv')))
            df = pd.read_csv(self.file_name)

            if len(df) == 0:
                msg.showinfo('No records', 'No records')

            # Now display the DF in 'Table' object
            # under'pandastable' module

            self.f2 = tk.Frame(parent)
            self.table = Table(self.f2, dataframe=df, read_only=True, height=300, width=600)
            self.f2.pack(padx=4, pady=100)
            self.table.show()

        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print(e)
            msg.showerror('Error in opening file', e.filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Main()
```